# Change in wall toilet back to in floor toilet

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, concrete

I have a small 1 bath house, single story, built on a slab.  A previous owner changed the bathroom from a floor mount toilet to a wall mount toilet and I'm interested in changing this back to a floor mount toilet.

Anyone know who I should contact about this type of work?  I suspect that some wall + slab work would be involved here.  This seems beyond the scope of most plumbers, but maybe I just need to find the right one?

Thanks!

Comment: Where I'm sitting (Malta) I'd expect my plumber to be able to do this. And I only mention this to suggest that you might want to give readers a clue as to your own location - perhaps it's one of those places where the Worshipful Company of Toilet Movers has an absolute lock on the type of work you want done and you ask someone from the wrong guild at your own peril. Oh, and while you wait for an answer, pick up the telephone, call a plumber and ask 'Do you ... ?'

Answer (score 1):

Talk to plumbers first. They’ll probably be able to do or sub out the concrete work.

My only comment is that you’re planning a lot of work for what might not be tremendous benefit. (If, for instance, your existing toilet needs to be replaced, you might find that prices for new ones aren’t astronomical.)